# .pack ttk and sticky in Python 3.5

Tags: python, import, tkinter, sticky, ttk

I've found out how to create a replacement logo for Tk, and to remove the Tk from the window. I have not however been able to find any existence on how to sticky any buttons or such. I've tried creating a class, and a def create_widget, but for some reason I'm getting errors in PyDev debugging. It keeps saying sticky = N + E is undefined. I thought importing ttk would automatically allow me to edit these buttons via self, but when I do self I have to change everything around and then the imports won't allow root. I believe this problem is because I'm not importing the right way, due to the fact I have replaced the logo and removed tk. My question is, how does .pack work and is there something I'm missing majorly in this code?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
import tempfile

ICON =     (b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00h\x05\x00\x00'
    b'\x16\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
    b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01') + b'\x00'*1282 + b'\xff'*64

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)


root = tkinter.Tk()

buttonstyle = ttk.Style()
buttonstyle.map("C.TButton",
    foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
    background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'black'), ('active', 'white')]
    )
colored_btn = ttk.Button(text="Activate", style="C.TButton").pack()

b = ttk.Button(root, text='Rename')
b.pack()

style = ttk.Style()


style.theme_settings("default", {
   "TCombobox": {
       "configure": {"padding": 5},
       "map": {
           "background": [("active", "green2"),
                          ("!disabled", "green4")],
           "fieldbackground": [("!disabled", "green3")],
           "foreground": [("focus", "OliveDrab1"),
                          ("!disabled", "OliveDrab2")]
       }
   }
})

combo = ttk.Combobox().pack()

style.layout("TMenubutton", [
   ("Menubutton.background", None),
   ("Menubutton.button", {"children":
       [("Menubutton.focus", {"children":
           [("Menubutton.padding", {"children":
               [("Menubutton.label", {"side": "left", "expand": 1})]
           })]
       })]
   }),
])

mbtn = ttk.Menubutton(text='Rename')
mbtn.pack()

root.title("Rename")
root.iconbitmap(default = ICON_PATH)

root.geometry("700x300")

label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Rename")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've looked on Google, Python Doc 3.5, and youtube. But every support is not saying anything about how to .grid(row = ... ) on a .pack

Comment: "how does pack work" is way too broad for stackoverflow, and "how to .grid... on a .pack" makes no sense. Grid and pack are two different ways to accomplish the same task. It's like grilling vs frying, or driving a car vs driving a bus. You can't "grill on a fry" or "drive a car on a bus". You might want to start by reading http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your imports:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
import tempfile
```

Now look at the `sticky` code that reportedly failed:

```
sticky = N + E
```

The references `N` and `E` (which are just `'n'` and `'e'`) are in `tkinter`, so you'll need to access them like other objects in that package, with the `tkinter.` prefix:

```
sticky = tkinter.N + tkinter.E
```

or just use a literal string:

```
sticky='ne'
```

Comment: Could you show me an example on `b = ttk.Button(root, text='Rename')
b.pack()` on a description the .grid(row =... looks?

Comment: @mydiax - Are you using `grid` and `pack` together?

Comment: Not really sure how it's suppose to look, I got the code for replace logo Tk on here using the same imports, then went to ttk. So I went to Python 3.5 Docs, and it uses .pack, so I guess I'm using .pack. I started off using Tkinter following tutorials and learned how to .grid and create class Application(Frame), and root.mainloop, so I know how to self with the regular Tkinter, but not with ttk, what I'm trying to say is that I'm not really sure what to do with the `.pack` and Python Docs doesn't say anything about it either in ttk.

Comment: Combined with your comment above about "using grid on a pack" which doesn't make any sense, it sounds like you need to do some significant research here. I recommend the [docs on Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).